# Show system settings fragment/activity inside your own app

Tags: android

I need to display application settings screen for a specific system application in my own Android app. Currently I can only launch it as a separate activity and on a timer in the background I check if user performed the action (Force stop) and then re-lauch my activity.

What I have now:

```
public static void showInstalledAppDetails(Context context, String packageName)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I would like to integrate the settings screen into my own application, I have tried using ActivityGroup and then launching system settings as child activity. The operation fails with Security Exception (lack of MANAGE_USB permission).

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks, Swav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this work?

No, sorry. You cannot combine multiple activities from disparate processes into a single UI.

Comment: I presume using fragments would fail for the same reason, am I right?

Comment: @Swav: You have no way to access individual fragments out of another application in the first place.